# Blowfish results are different between OpenSSL and Golang

Tags: c, go, openssl, blowfish

I want to read VIM encoded files in Go. [This code](https://gist.github.com/grafi-tt/94015cc8c8f656420fb019a9c1e22f0f) works good enough for small file so I've decided to convert it to Go. Key generation works fine, but Blowfish encoding does not. I've traced the problem to different outcome from BF_encrypt and cipher.Encrypt(...).

*Input*

```
key: c904a7a85bbd975324c5083ed96ff022f25e062da1d575b2462c2c98d8d64d9d
data: 538b7759834d3418
```

*Output*

```
Golang: b5cf33144acbc794
C:      90baa70ec3e44867
```

Golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish"
)

func main() {
    key := []byte{0xc9, 0x04, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0x5b, 0xbd, 0x97, 0x53, 0x24, 0xc5, 0x08, 0x3e, 0xd9, 0x6f, 0xf0, 0x22, 0xf2, 0x5e, 0x06, 0x2d, 0xa1, 0xd5, 0x75, 0xb2, 0x46, 0x2c, 0x2c, 0x98, 0xd8, 0xd6, 0x4d, 0x9d}
    data := []byte{0x53, 0x8b, 0x77, 0x59, 0x83, 0x4d, 0x34, 0x18}

    cipher, err := blowfish.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("key: %x\n", key)
    fmt.Printf("data: %x\n", data)

    encrypted := make([]byte, 8)
    cipher.Encrypt(encrypted, data)
    fmt.Printf("encrypted: %x\n", encrypted)
}
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/blowfish.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

/*
clang test1.c -o test1 \
-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/lib \
-lcrypto
./test1
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char key[32] = {0xc9, 0x04, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0x5b, 0xbd, 0x97, 0x53, 0x24, 0xc5, 0x08, 0x3e, 0xd9, 0x6f, 0xf0, 0x22, 0xf2, 0x5e, 0x06, 0x2d, 0xa1, 0xd5, 0x75, 0xb2, 0x46, 0x2c, 0x2c, 0x98, 0xd8, 0xd6, 0x4d, 0x9d};
    unsigned char data[8] = {0x53, 0x8b, 0x77, 0x59, 0x83, 0x4d, 0x34, 0x18};

    BF_KEY bf_key;
    BF_set_key(&bf_key, 32, key);

    printf("key: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) printf("%02x", key[j]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("data: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) printf("%02x", data[j]);
    printf("\n");

    BF_encrypt((unsigned int*)data, &bf_key);

    printf("encrypted: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) printf("%02x", data[j]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Can you see where the problem is?

Comment: Interesting.  Try PHP for a tie-breaker  :)  .  I've used one C++ blowfish source (Jim Conger's) that used a different byte order in its output than everyone else's, but that isn't the issue here.

Comment: You should probably find some [Blowfish test vectors](https://www.google.com/search?q=blowfish+test+vectors) and see which (if any) arrives at the correct result.

Comment: According to the [`BF_encrypt` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bf_encrypt): *"BF_encrypt() and BF_decrypt() are the lowest level functions for Blowfish encryption. They encrypt/decrypt the first 64 bits of the vector pointed by data, using the key key. These functions should not be used unless you implement 'modes' of Blowfish. The alternative is to use BF_ecb_encrypt(). If you still want to use these functions, you should be aware that they take each 32-bit chunk in host-byte order, which is little-endian on little-endian platforms and big-endian on big-endian ones"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the endianness of variable `data` and `encrypted`. In the C code, `data` (8-bytes) is converted from byte array to `unsigned int`(32-bit little-endian), then being encrypted in place. It affects the endianness of both input and encrypted result. To get same result in Golang, you must perform endian conversion, e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    "encoding/binary"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/blowfish"
)

func convertEndian(in []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    //Read byte array as uint32 (little-endian)
    var v1, v2 uint32
    buf := bytes.NewReader(in)
    if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &v1); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &v2); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    //convert uint32 to byte array
    out := make([]byte, 8)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(out, v1)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(out[4:], v2)

    return out, nil
}

func main() {
    key := []byte{0xc9, 0x04, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0x5b, 0xbd, 0x97, 0x53, 0x24, 0xc5, 0x08, 0x3e, 0xd9, 0x6f, 0xf0, 0x22, 0xf2, 0x5e, 0x06, 0x2d, 0xa1, 0xd5, 0x75, 0xb2, 0x46, 0x2c, 0x2c, 0x98, 0xd8, 0xd6, 0x4d, 0x9d}
    data := []byte{0x53, 0x8b, 0x77, 0x59, 0x83, 0x4d, 0x34, 0x18}

    //Add: This is equal to: (unsigned int *)data in C
    cdata, _ := convertEndian(data)

    cipher, err := blowfish.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("key: %x\n", key)
    fmt.Printf("data: %x\n", cdata)

    encrypted := make([]byte, 8)
    cipher.Encrypt(encrypted, cdata)
    fmt.Printf("encrypted-1: %x\n", encrypted)

    //Add: This is equal to {uint32, uint32} --> byte array
    ce, _ := convertEndian(encrypted)
    fmt.Printf("encrypted-2: %02x\n", ce)
}
```